# Object of class Illuminate\Http\Response could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I've created a artisan command which call a function from an already built controller (in the handle function) and on running it through artisan i got this error:

```
 Object of class Illuminate\Http\Response could not be converted to int
```

Comment: Do you `return` something from the command?

Comment: @shaedrich yes i did

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't.

Comment: Could you please add the code that causes this error. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

handle function should not return a value.
my code worked after removing the return from handle function.

Note: Thanks to @shaedrich

Answer (score 0):

you should remove **return** from your command and it will work

Comment: Could you add a line of code so the answer is more  clear? Thanks